# Eclipse CDT: combine a make project with a cmake one

Tags: eclipse, makefile, cmake, eclipse-cdt, dependency-management

I have a standard C project in Eclipse CDT. Naturally it uses `make`. I have decided to add some JSON support to my application to be able to load/save its configuration in a readable format that the user (if such desire occurs) can alter those manually and/or through an external tool. I've looked up two options so far namely **Jansson** and **Json-C**. The problem is that both are using `cmake`, which, if I recall correctly, can be imported in Eclipse CDT without problems (though in itself CDT can't create cmake projects).

I was thinking of adding a script for the pre-build step of my project that runs `cmake` (as an external command) and sets up the JSON library (static and/or dynamic) so that when the build process of my projects starts the library file will be available.

Is there a better way to combine a cmake with a make project in Eclipse CDT? I know that cmake basically generates a `Makefile` but I've never done such a combination before.

Even if there is a JSON C library somewhere out ther that uses `make` (I'm 99.9% sure there is such thing :D) I'd still like to know how to tackle this situation.